# i want to change the url using python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm new to python and I can't figure out a way to do this so I'm asking for someone to help

I have URL like this `https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4` and I want to remove the last part `go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4` of URL and also change `/f/` with `/d/` so I can get the URL to be like this `https://abc.xyz/d/b`

`/b` it change regular I have tried use somthing like this didn't work 
`newurl = oldurl.replace('/f/','/d/').rsplit("/", 1)[0]`)

Comment: You should look into using the `urllib` library for this. https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#module-urllib

Comment: `newurl = url.replace('/f/','/d/').rsplit("/", 1)[0]` worked fine for me...

Comment: yes it's work for me now too lol idon't now why it didn't worked at the first time

Answer (score -2, accepted):

What you had almost worked.  The change is to remove the trailing right paren `)` at the end of your assignment to `newurl`.  The following works in both Python 2 and 3:

```
oldurl = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
newurl = oldurl.replace('/f/','/d/').rsplit("/", 1)[0]
print(newurl)
```

But a more idiomatic expression can be obtain thru the `re` standard lib:

```
import re
old_url = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
new_url = re.sub("/f/.+", r"/d/b", old_url)
print(new_url)
```

Answer (score 3):

Late answer, but you can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace `"/f/.+"` with `"/d/b"`, i.e.:

```
old_url = "https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4"
new_url = re.sub("/f/.+", r"/d/b", old_url)
# https://abc.xyz/d/b
```

---

[Regex Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/txWYfn/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can apply `re.sub` twice:

```
import re
s = 'https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4'
new_s = re.sub('(?<=\.\w{3}/)\w', 'd', re.sub('(?<=/)\w+$', '', s))
```

Output:

```
'https://abc.xyz/d/b/'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import re

domain_str = 'https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4'

#find all appearances of the first part of the url
matches = re.findall('(https?:\/\/\w*\.\w*\/?)',domain_str)

#add your domain extension to each of the results
d_extension = 'd'
altered_domains = []
for res in matches:
    altered_domains.append(res + d_extension)
print(altered_domains)
```

exmaple input:
'https://abc.xyz/f/b/go_cc_Jpterxvid_avi_mp4'
and output:
['https://abc.xyz/d']